# spacebar on OnScreen Keyboard C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, space

I start programming this week and my partner gave me a onscreen keyboard to do. I only need to click on spacebar on the keyboard and show a space on my textbox, how do a do that?

```
    private void btnSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: your question is not good enough to explain your query, can you please explain it properly?

Comment: I have a onscreen keyboard to enter security codes avoiding keyloggers or spies on user computer. I have numbers and letters and i use the text on them to fill the textbox. Now i need to create the spacebar action on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `TextBox` with the Name `MyTextBox` you could do:

```
this.MyTextBox.Text = " ";
```

or if you want to add a `Space`:

```
this.myTextBox.Text += " ";
```

Comment: It doesn't worked. Now when i click the spacebar the textbox gets empty.

Comment: Yeah. Because you choosed the `this.MyTextBox.Text = " ";` Code. Then the Content of the Textbox is " " which looks like empty. you could choose the bottom code. then a " " is added to the existing text.

Comment: Nice thanks, now worked, but i've found another solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I added one line of code:

```
MyTextBox.Text += (sender as Button).Text;
```

On the code and set the spacebar button text to " ". Now when I click on the spacebar button it shows a space. To identify the spacebar button I've used a png image with "spacebar" on it.

Thanks for all of you that tried to help me.